# Scripting a MySQL query in Unix using daemon in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, daemon

I'm trying to make an "at" job work at a given time, for testing purposes I'm using $time but this will be a datetime that I get from a separate MySQL query.  In the command line I go like this:

```
echo "mysql -e 'UPDATE admin SET row1=row2 WHERE id=1;'" | at now
```

And I get a "job 36 at 2010-10-28 15:05".  in PHP I tried going like this:

```
exec("\"mysql -e 'UPDATE admin SET row1=row2 WHERE id=1'\" | at $time");
```

But the query doesn't run.  Worse, I have no idea what is happening.

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

returns "daemon" though.  How can I echo whatever response I'm getting from the exec command? ideally I guess it would say "job 36 at 2010-10-28 15:05" or something similar.

Also, I have a .my.cnf file in my dir that specifies the db, login and password to use, does the daemon need to have one also for these to work?

[from the answers I can tell I wasn't clear about what I am trying to do.  I need to

- A. Run a mySQL query to get a date/time and an id
- B. Schedule an update to take place to rows that match the id at the date/time

I'd already done "A" and was using "1" for the id and "now" for the time while testing.  I'll look into PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the *at* command, but it seems to help run commands at a certain time.

If you're trying to write a scheduled script in PHP there are better ways to do it. Just write a CLI script and use the cron to schedule it. As Svisstack notes, if you're running MySQL queries use an in-built function such as PDO rather than system commands.

If you're just running systems commands, I'm not sure why you're using PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps in [`safe_mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)? If yes then your `|` is getting escaped automatically. Per the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> With safe mode enabled, the command
>   string is escaped with
>   escapeshellcmd(). Thus, echo y | echo
>   x becomes echo y \| echo x.

Comment: With this I can echo what I'd done so I think yes I was in safe mode, but the query still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information by using the other parameters for the `exec` command.  Try running this and see the output.

```
$output = array();
$return = false;
$last_line = exec("\"mysql -e 'UPDATE admin SET row1=row2 WHERE id=1'\" | at now", $output, $return);

var_dump($last_line);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return);
```

Also, it looks like when you ran it at the command line, you `echo`'ed the MySQL command, but when you put it in the PHP code, it's not doing the `echo` anymore.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference since I'm not to familiar with `at`, but I thought that I could offer some troubleshooting help.

```
$last_line = exec("echo \"mysql -e 'UPDATE admin SET row1=row2 WHERE id=1'\" | at now", $output, $return);
```

Answer (score 0):

A missing `echo` in your second statement / exec? (and I'd rather use `popen` / `proc_open` the `at $time`, and `fwrite` the command for at to execute (after which you close the input stream, then the program. Use `atq` to verify wether it worked, and be aware the current use may be disallowed `at` jobs (normally found in files like `/etc/at.allow` or `/etc/at.deny`)